# docker: freeze library dependencies

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Docker file

```
FROM debian
MAINTAINER Me
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.2.2
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential \
         ca-certificates \
         git \
         fonts-liberation \
         libfreeimage3 \
         imagemagick \
         python \
         python-numpy \
         python-pip \
         curl \
         xsltproc \
         xz-utils \
    && curl -L https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz | tar -xJ \
    && ln -s /node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/bin \
    && ln -s /node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/bin \
    && curl -L http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz | tar -xJ \
    && ln -s /ffmpeg-*/ffm* /usr/bin \
    && pip install moviepy \
    && apt-get remove -y \
         python-pip \
         curl \
         xz-utils \
    && rm -Rf /tmp/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

what is the correct way to freeze library dependencies such as imagemagic, git etc... when doing apt-get install - is there a way to freeze versions similar to how it is done on npm shrinkwrap?

any advice much appreciated

Comment: If you are using apt-get is not possible, because old versions are removed from the archives. The only solution that comes to mind is to download the deb packages locally and then `COPY` them and install them in locally with [dpkg](https://wiki.debian.org/dpkg).

Answer (score 2):

Based on [How to tweak "dpkg -l" output - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/538263/612216):

```
dpkg-query --show -f='${binary:Package}=${Version} \\\n' build-essential \
     ca-certificates \
     git \
     fonts-liberation \
     libfreeimage3 \
     imagemagick \
     python \
     python-numpy \
     python-pip \
     curl \
     xsltproc \
     xz-utils
```

Run this command in a docker container based on this Dockerfile to get the text to copy into your Dockerfile.